# close all figures - of all open matlab instances / processes

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-figure

I frequently work with several matlab instances, and sometimes I would like to close all figures - regardless of the matlab instance that produced them.

I know matlab runs on java and has system level access - what is the way to do this in windows (besides - obviously - just not use multiple instances of matlab and clean the figures up per-instance)?

Comment: of course, as long as it's callable from within matlab - and this should be easy, as cmd/powershell commands are directly accessible with `!yourcommand`